# The replace function in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, contains

I have this function in Java, that given a text, an array of words and a char, should check if the words in the "words" array exist in the text, and if they do, surround them with the given char "c".

Here's what i've come up with:

```
public void replaceString(BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out, char c, String[] words){

    String line_in = in.readLine();
    String result = null;

        while (line_in != null) {

            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {

                if (line_in.toLowerCase().contains(words[j].toLowerCase())) {

                    result = line_in.replace(words[j], bold + words[j] + bold);

                }

                else
                    result = line_in;

            }

            out.write(result);
            out.newLine();
            line_in = in.readLine();

        }

}
```

But, for some reason, the replace method is not doing anything...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are testing for a lower-cased word in a lower-cased string . This doesn't mean that the replace triggers, which is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm's logic is incorrect: the `result` is set to the result of only the last iteration of the `for` loop, so if the last word is not detected, you get the original line.

You should change the code as follows:

```
result = line_in;
for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    if (result.toLowerCase().contains(words[j].toLowerCase())) {
        result = result.replace(words[j], bold + words[j] + bold);
    }
}
```

Now `result` has the result of the last replacement that has happened, or the original `line_in` if none of the words were detected.

**Note:** Your logic checks for case-insensitive match, but your `replace` code does case-sensitive match. This may result in issues when the input is in mixed case.

Comment: i still reach the same problem... looks like the replace method is not doing anything...

Comment: @laker001 - Try to make sure your code actually goes into the "if" section. Regardless, I think that condition is redundant, and you can use "replace" directly, as I suggested (seperately) in my answer.

Comment: @OferLando it goes into the if section and reaches the replace line, but simply nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can probably drop the validation inside the loop and go for:

```
for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    result = line_in.replace("(?i)" + words[j], bold + words[j] + bold);
}
```

This will populate "result" with updated value - covering the case-sensitivity options built-in with the replace itself (thanks to the "?i" option).

Comment: with you're code, the program enters into the replace line, but the output is always the same as the input.

Comment: Can you please provide some examples? One "source" string and one set of "words"?

Comment: By the way, could it be that "bold" is not initialized properly, and therefore the replace works fine - but it just replaces words[j] with itself, e.g. <null>words[j]<null>?

Comment: The problem is that you're function only works for low case or upper case words, if there are low and upper case letters in the same word, the replace doesn't do anything

Comment: (?i) tells replace to be case-insensitive. It should work. That's why I asked for examples, to understand what could we be missing here.